# css to align title and everything below it

Tags: css

I wish to align the title and summary(click the plus sign in site below)
as shown in the screenshot
my site 
http://pligg.marsgibson.info/
screenshot
http://i47.tinypic.com/ntn55.jpg

suggest css for this

Comment: You should show us the HTML/CSS you have already and what you've tried to fix the problem you're having.

Comment: My css here
http://pligg.marsgibson.info/templates/wistie/css/style.css
I tried to use 
margin: 0px 10px 0px 75px;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
in
.title h2 span, .title h2 a{

but didnt work

Comment: -1 and also voting to close the OP.   _"here's my website, fix it for me"_ type questions are unwelcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your current markup, a simple fix can be:

**CSS**

```
.title h2 {
    color: #187AAB;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 32px;
    position: relative;
}
.title h2 span {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Print-screen:**
[image]

---

What I did was to give some left and right [padding](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/padding) to the `h2` element, to limit the space available for the text inside it.

Then, to place the avatar on the proper place, I've used the CSS [position](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position).

---

## EDITED

To address the issue of your trigger element, add to its CSS:

```
p.trigger {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

---

## EDITED

To address the height issue mentioned on the comment!

See this working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Pwvfy/1/)!

**jQUery**

```
// run only if elements are found
if ($('.title').size()>=1) {

  // initialize variables
  var $target = $('.title'),
      size    = 0,
      count   = $('.title').size();

  // for each element found
  $target.each(function() {

    // check the tallest element
    if (size===0) {
        size = $target.outerHeight(true);
    } else {
        sizeTMP = $target.outerHeight(true);
        size = (sizeTMP> size) ? sizeTMP : size;
    }

    // decrease the counter
    count--;

    // counter is 0, set the height
    if (count===0) {
        $target.css({ "height" : size + "px" });
    }

  });
}
```

**Ps:** The CSS `display` declaration for the class `.subtext1` must be updated to: `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks but doing this will make the jquery(plus sign) to work not effectively
now only a particular area is needed to click to expand/contract remaining summary
what could be the reason why its not expanding/contracting on click any part of plus sign ?

Comment: @user1445629, To fix that, just add to your `p.trigger` this CSS: `position:relative;z-index:1;`.

Comment: Yes it works thanks
last thing 
note the difference between two line title and one line title
the box height is same for both 
can the height of single line title be less 2 line title ?
see the image
http://i50.tinypic.com/iddjdw.jpg

Comment: @user1445629, that was not the issue addressed on the question! But you can solve that with a bit of jQuery to adjust the element height to the tallest one! See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Pwvfy/)! Also added this to the answer.

Comment: adding the jquery further increases the gap between title and "Posted by"
postedby needs to be adjusted 
for the 1 line case it should stick just below the title

Comment: @user1445629, just set the `.subtext1` CSS to `display:inline-block` and use the updated jQuery function on my answer. [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Pwvfy/1/).

Comment: Thanks but doing this shifts the "posted by" to be above but still the box height is same

Comment: @user1445629, At this point I don't really understand your issue, I've given you solutions for many problems, and by my tests, all is getting into place, but now I cannot grasp your goal. I suggest you take a decision regarding this question (either accept it or not), and post a new question explaining your current problem!